# How to add Translator Text service to my Azure account

Tags: azure, machine-translation

I have an Azure account and I want to activate the Machine Translation feature on it, which is described here?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/

But I can't find that service anywhere in the Azure portal. Does anybody know how to activate that?

Answer (score 0):

Translation is part of what Microsoft calls "Cognitive Services" (Vision, Speech, Language, Search and Decision).

You have two options to activate this: Single-Service or Multi-Service subscription.

Single-Service subscription (only activates one of the services below)
 1. Connect to Azure portal
 2. Click on "Create a resource"
 3. Under "Marketplace", select "AI + Machine Learning"
 4. In your case, select "Language"

Multi-Service subscription (activates more than one of the Cognitive services)
 1. Connect to Azure portal
 2. Click on "Create a resource"
 3. Search for "Cognitive Services"

Comment: Thx. Creating a Cognitive Services resource worked. But I wasn't able to create a Language resource. I only saw Language Understanding, which does not seem to include Machine Translation.

Comment: Did you look for translator text API? What are you trying to accomplish?